# silverlight, using Observables on WCF calls, casting IEvent<T> where T : AsyncCompletedEventArgs

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, delegates, system.reactive

i have a question using Observables in Silverlight 4 to make WCF calls.
Consider the simple webservice call below.

```
var adminclient = ServiceProxy.WithFactory<AuthenticationClient>();
var results= Observable.FromEvent<AuthorizeAdministratorCompletedEventArgs>(
   s => adminclient.AuthorizeAdministratorCompleted += s,
   s => adminclient.AuthorizeAdministratorCompleted -= s).ObserveOnDispatcher();

adminclient.AuthorizeAdministratorAsync();
results.Subscribe(e =>
{
   //Enable UI Button
});
```

i have implemented an extension method, that wraps the subscribe method, it does some error validation on the return.

---

On the return *results.Subscribe(e =>*

```
e is System.Collections.Generic.Event<AuthorizeAdministratorCompletedEventArgs>
```

almost every query will have a different return type such as:

```
e is System.Collections.Generic.Event<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>
```

if i had a wrapper that looked something like this, how can i cast every type of *xxxCompletedEventArgs* to its base type *AsyncCompletedEventArgs* so that i can access *e.EventArgs* and inspect the *Error* property

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> onNext = null, Action onError = null, Action onFinal = null)
{
    Action<TSource> onNextWrapper = (s) =>
    {                   
    var args = (System.Collections.Generic.IEvent<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>)s;

    try
       {                            
          if (WCFExceptionHandler.HandleError(args.EventArgs))
             {
                if (onNext != null)
                   onNext(s);
             }
             else
             {
                if (onError != null)
                   onError();
             }
        }
        finally
        {
           if (onFinal != null)
              onFinal();
        }
   };

   return source.Subscribe<TSource>(onNextWrapper, (e) => { throw e; });
}
```

The code above will fail

Unable to cast object of type `'System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[MyProject.Provider.AuthorizeAdministratorCompletedEventArgs]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEvent`1[System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs]'`

This is the method definition of *WCFExceptionHandler.HandleError(args.EventArgs))*

```
public static bool HandleError(AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably change you extension method so that it acts to handle the the events as a non blocking operator (much the same as the majority of the Rx extension method operators). Something like:

```
public static IObservable<IEvent<TEventArgs>> GetHandledEvents<TEventArgs>(this IObservable<IEvent<TEventArgs>> source)
    where TEventArgs : AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{
    return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<IEvent<TEventArgs>>(observer =>
        {
            return source.Subscribe(evt =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (WCFExceptionHandler.HandleError(evt.EventArgs))
                        {
                            observer.OnNext(evt);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            observer.OnError(new Exception("Some Exception"));
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        observer.OnError(new Exception("Some Other Exception"));
                    }
                }, 
                observer.OnError, 
                observer.OnCompleted);
        });
}
```

Then call it through:

```
results.GetHandledEvents()
  .Finally(() => DoSomethingFinally())
  .Subscribe(e =>
  {
   //Enable UI Button
  },
  ex => HandleException(ex),
  () => HandleComplete());
```

I *think* this should solve your issues as the events will funnel through as their original type and it ensures that `HandleError` gets event args that are the correct type.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer, but "observer.OnNext(evt);" will not compile, The best overloaded method match for 'System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.IEvent<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>>.OnNext(System.Collections.Generic.IEvent<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Neil - Sorry, Observable.CreateWithDisposable<IEvent<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>> needed to be Observable.CreateWithDisposable<IEvent<TEventArgs>>. I've updated my example. That any good?

Comment: Yup, also figured it out, thanks, last problem is that my finally statement contains, "observer.OnCompleted();", but if i call "adminclient.AuthorizeAdministratorAsync();" twice, lets say with 2 different parameters, only the one executes the OnNext, the second does not see the event handler. Any suggestions
                    }

Comment: @Neil - Option 1, you could remove the OnCompleted to make the operator more flexible. There's nothing wrong with allowing multiple values through. Option 2, your call to adminclient.AuthorizeAdministratorAsync() could return the Observable which would mean you would need to Subscribe for each call to this method (this would be my preference if you have access to the code for this method as the intent seems clearer). Option 3, look into the Repeat operator which will allow the source to complete and will then resubscribe.

Comment: I've gone with option 3, although its not very consistent when making web service calls, if the call is like so "client.GetLookupsByLookupgroupAsync(LookupGroupItems.CompanyType);" where LookupGroupItems is an enum, hence called for many enums, it will only work correctly if the service responds very quickly and the observable does not get a chance to unhook the handler. Thanks alot for all your help

Comment: @Neil - No problem, and like I said I'd rather return a separate observable for each method call. That way you can compose multiple calls in what ever way you want (grouping them all together to get a similar outcome to your current solution), you shouldn't have any problem with race conditions (so long as the observables are cold), and if you subscribe one at a time you know exactly which results apply to which method calls. Feel free to ask another question and I'll try and come up with some quick examples.